# How to use RGBA in an onmouseleave event?

Tags: javascript, html

This doesn't seem to work when changing the background of a table in HTML:

```js
onmouseleave="this.bgColor='rgba(24,58,0,0.85)'"
```

Do I have the syntax wrong?

Comment: Hey there, first, bgcolor is only valid on a handful elements, such as `<td>` and `<body>`, for the other 99% of elements, you probably want something like `this.style.backgroundColor='rgba(24,58,0,0.85)'`. Second, why have you tagged with `jscript`? That refers to shell scripting via `Windows Script Host`

Comment: It is in a td.
Adding style/backgroundColor/both does nothing.
Also, I thought jscript was short for javascript

Comment: it refers to microsofts implementation of ECMAScript and it used in IE (and probably edge?) and also command line scripting under windows script host, but not javascript in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
this.style.backgroundColor='rgba(24,58,0,0.85)';
```

Comment: Adding style/backgroundColor/both does nothing.

Comment: @user6506939 me too

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fe5BNhzv_VWh1GVwVt7CdSTs2mUH8qBJT_p1LO05-Ms/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @user6506939 No no, edit your post to contain a minimal example that shows the problem.

Comment: I tried to, it was a lot bigger than that, but it doesn't matter because I found what was wrong - I was being an idiot and thinking it didn't work because I changed the onmouseleave and not the onmouseover; since the original color and mouseleave is the same

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of how to change the background of an element on `onmouseleave`

```
<input onmouseleave="applyRGBA(this)" id="myInput" type="text"/>

function applyRGBA (e) {
    e.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(24, 58, 0, 0.85)';
}
```